# Is there a better approach to convert datetime.datetime objects from gmt to pst?

Tags: python, mysql, list

I am running a query through python in aws and getting the sql results in tuples which consists of datetime objects.

sample record:

```
'('BlaBla', '20190212', 'Blabla', 'job_name', 
  datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 13, 18, 4, 41),
  datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 13, 18, 4, 43))'
```

I using a logic on the above record and converting to the below

```
['BlaBla', '20190212', 'BlaBla', 'jobname', 
 '2019-02-13 14:26:49',
 '2019-02-13 14:26:52']
```

FYI, the times are not the same, i pasted the second record as a sample. The time is in GMT

Now i have a list of tuples , How do i convert the tuple's datetime objects into PST?

I have looked into astimezone function but i am getting

```
ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

also i tried

```
d = local_tz.localize(datetime(2019, 2, 13, 17, 1, 27),is_dst=None)
```

getting errors, Nothing seems to be working..

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: Can you provide full error responses

Comment: Thanks Jaba for response :) I have used the below function.

    def gmt_pst(time_stmp):
        time_stmp = time_stmp - datetime.timedelta(hours=8)
        return time_stmp
But i would like to use astimezone because of timezones

Comment: are you in GMT+8?

Comment: No , My Timezone is UTC

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to your db timezone. Is that GMT+0 then?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution based off the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone). I'm wondering if I'm missing something somewhere though, having to create all these tzinfo subclasses from scratch. I would expect them to be part of the datetime library to be honest.

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

ZERO = timedelta(0)
HOUR = timedelta(hours=1)

# A UTC class.

class UTC(tzinfo):
    """UTC"""

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

class PST(tzinfo):
    """PST"""

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return timedelta(hours=8) + self.dst(dt)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "PST"

    def dst(self, dt):
        # DST starts last Sunday in March
        d = datetime(dt.year, 4, 1)   # ends last Sunday in October
        self.dston = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
        d = datetime(dt.year, 11, 1)
        self.dstoff = d - timedelta(days=d.weekday() + 1)
        if self.dston <=  dt.replace(tzinfo=None) < self.dstoff:
            return timedelta(hours=1)
        else:
            return timedelta(0)

utc = UTC()
pst = PST()

>>>dt1 = datetime(2019,2,13,14,26,49, tzinfo=utc)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 13, 14, 26, 49, tzinfo=<dtime_test.UTC object at 0x00000180AF6F1F60>)

>>>dt1.astimezone(pst)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 13, 22, 26, 49, tzinfo=<dtime_test.PST object at 0x00000180AF934080>)
```

Comment: Did a little bit more searching. There's a 3rd party library called [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to avoid creating the tzinfo subclasses

Comment: Thank you, Honestly your code is well above on my head. I am very new to Py
Actually i have a list of tuples

 a_list=['blabla' , '20190201','blablah','job_name','2019-02-13 16:55:55','2019-02-13 22:01:02'],['blabla' , '20190201','blablah','job_name','2019-02-13 18:30:55','2019-02-13 20:01:02']

in the above record a_list{4] and a_list[5] are in UTC, because i am running the  sql query in AWS cluster which has UTC TZ 
I am trying to get a record like 
'blabla' , '20190201','blablah','job_name','2019-02-13 16:55:55','2019-02-13 22:01:02']
here a_list[4] and a_list[5] should be in pst

Comment: In that case, before you convert your tuple into a list, add one more step to inject the tzinfo into the datetime object and convert it to pst first. Unpack your tuple to extract the datetime object and then 1.```dt_utc = datetime_object.replace(tzinfo=utc)``` 2. ```dt_pst = dt_utc.astimezone(pst)``` . You can then proceed to construct your list after that using ```dt_pst```